# C++ AMP nested loop

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, gpu, gpgpu, c++-amp

I'm working on a project that requires massive parallel computing. However, the tricky problem is that, the project contains a nested loop, like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<19; ++i){
    for(int j=0; j<57; ++j){
        //the computing section
    }
}
```

To achieve the highest gain, I need to parallelise those two levels of loops. Like this:

```
parallel_for_each{
    parallel_for_each{
        //computing section
    }
}
```

I tested and found that AMP doesn't support nested for loops. Anyone have any idea on this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You could, as @High Performance Mark suggest collapse the two loops into one. However, you don't need to do this with C++ AMP because it supports 2 and 3 dimensional `extent`s on `array`s and `array_view`s. You can the use an `index` as a multi-dimensional index.

```
array<float, 2> x(19,57);
parallel_for_each(x.extent, [=](index<2> idx) restrict(amp)
{
    x[idx] = func(x[idx]);
});

float func(const float v) restrict(amp) { return v * v; }
```

You can access the individual sub-indeces in `idx` using:

```
int row = idx[0]; 
int col = idx[1];
```

You should also consider the amount of work being done by `computing section`. If it is relatively small you may want to have each thread process more than one element of the array, `x`.

The following article is also worth reading as just like the CPU if your loops do not access memory efficiently it can have a big impact on performance. [Arrays are Row Major in C++ AMP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nativeconcurrency/archive/2012/05/10/arrays-are-row-major-in-c-amp.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

So collapse the loops:

```
for(int ij=0; ij<19*57; ++ij){
        //if required extract i and j from ij
        //the computing section
    }
}
```

Comment: You could, and I suspect that's how you would do it in CUDA. However C++ AMP has a simpler approach for this. See my answer.